# Find the object's name via one of its properties

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object that holds all white chess pieces and an object that hold all black chess pieces. Now im writing an if statement that checks whether or not the pieces im working with are both the same color.

the code for objects is:

```
var whiteFgrs = {King:"&#9812", Queen:"&#9813", Fortress:"&#9814", Bishop:"&#9815", Knight:"&#9816", Peasant:"&#9817"};
var blackFgrs = {King:"&#9818", Queen:"&#9819", Fortress:"&#9820", Bishop:"&#9821", Knight:"&#9822", Peasant:"&#9823"};
```

and the code that stores the value of chosen positions:

```
var value1=document.getElementById(elemId1).lastChild.nodeValue;
var value2=document.getElementById(element.id).lastChild.nodeValue;
```

This returns the piece (eg. "&#9817"). How do I check if this code is a part of whiteFgrs or blackFgrs?

Comment: Iterate over the object to see if it contains the piece.

Comment: Easiest way could be to loop over `whiteFgrs` and `blackFgrs` to see which one contains it.

Comment: well, you could loop over the keys/values to figure out which one contains that value, but there's likely a better way, such as working with an internal object and then updating the dom to reflect rather than the other way around.

Comment: Open firebug, navigate to DOM, expand DOM and locate the object - browse the object and locate required property. Adjust your code accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you *could* look it up in the objects like suggested by the others, but there's a much more simple way to figure out whether a piece is black or white:

```
value < "&#9818" ? "white" : "black";
// or rather, as `nodeValue` gives you the plain text without html entities:
value < "\u265a" ? "white" : "black";
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate and check:

```
var colorValue = "&#9817";
for (var piece in whiteFgrs) {
    if (whiteFgs[piece] == colorValue) {
        //found it!
    }
}

//If not found in white figures, check black figures.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this check very often you could also create an index for faster lookup e.g.:

```
var index = Object.keys(whiteFgrs).reduce(function(idx, name){idx[whiteFgrs[name]]=name;return idx;},{});

index['&#9817']; // === 'Peasant'
```